# Angular: Display nothing in DOM incase of Null

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am removing elements of an array if they match with elements of another array. I am getting an issue here, when I try to print this new modified array in HTML, it prints nothing for that particular index but, occupies the row. I want it not to occupy any row of select if the array has null/undefined values. How can I do that? I have tried few things, but couldn't find any help.

Here's the code:

> TS

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.subAdminData.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < this.subAdminAllData.length; j++)
        {
          if(this.subAdminData[i].roles == this.subAdminAllData[j])
          {
            delete this.subAdminAllData[j]; // this removes the element but when I try to print this 
                                            // array in HTML using *ngFor then it is printing empty
                                            // values for the deleted values meaning it's occupying a 
                                            // full row of select with nothing in it
          }
        }
    }
```

> HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <select class="custom-select" size = "5" name= "subadminrights" required style = "width: 100%;">
          <option selected disabled value = "Select admin rights">Select sub administrative rights: </option>
          <option value="full" *ngFor = "let saData of subAdminAllData">
            
            {{saData}}</option>
            <!-- occupies a row with nothing in it if the array index has null value -->

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're using a wrong method to delete an item from the array. You need to change `delete this.subAdminAllData[j]` to `this.subAdminAllData.splice(j,1)`.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: By using the `delelte()` method you're just changing that element to `undefined`. There're a few methods to completely remove an item from an array. `Pop()`, `shift()`, `splice()` and `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment, you cannot use 'delete' for this but rather splice the item or other filtering. According to the code you provided the below filter should works.

```
    const filteredData = subAdminAllData.filter(data => !subAdminData.some((data2) => data2.roles === data));
```

With this code you should only keep subAdminAllData elements which are not a 'roles' property in your subAdminData array.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***lodash*** in your project, you could use ***_.difference*** or ***_.pullAll***

otherwise use ***Array.splice*** instead of delete, cause 'delete' removes the value but leaves an 'empty spot' in array - which is probably causing your issue